# Selecting column from table when name is stored in a local var

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this scenario:

```
declare @data table (Name varchar(100), Surname varchar(100), Extension int )

insert into @data 
    select 
        Comp.Name, Comp.Surname, Comp.Ext 
    from 
        Comp 
    where 
        Comp.Dept = 25

declare @fieldName varchar(100) = 'Name'
declare @getter varchar(100)
select @getter = (@fieldName) from @data where Extension=101
```

and I need to have in `@getter` the value of "Jhon" or "Mary" or "Peter" or whatever...

And if I'd change the value of `@fieldName` to `Surname` I should get their surnames.

Kind of difficult to explain but what I need is to reference a column name in a query that is stored in a local var

Comment: then you need to do dynamic sql

Comment: Perhaps a CASE would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below query.

```
DECLARE @fieldName VARCHAR(100) = 'Name'
DECLARE @getter VARCHAR(100)=''
DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(MAX) ='declare @data table (Name varchar(100), Surname varchar(100), Extension int )
                              insert into @data select Comp.Name, Comp.Surname, Comp.Ext from Comp where Comp.Dept=25
                              SELECT @Output='+@fieldName+' from @data where Extension=101'
EXEC sp_executesql  @sql,N'@Output NVARCHAR(100) OUT',@getter OUT
SELECT @getter
```

Comment: I thought so too, but that won't let him get the Value of the column out (@getter). How can you get the Value of a dynamic sql outside of its scope?

Comment: see the updated script.this will get the value in @getter

Comment: nice. Thx haven't seen that before. +1

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
declare @data table (Name varchar(100), Surname varchar(100), Extension int )
insert into @data select Comp.Name, Comp.Surname, Comp.Ext from Comp where Comp.Dept=25

declare @fieldName varchar(100) = 'Name'
declare @SQL varchar(100) = 'select ' + @fieldname + ' from @data where Extension=101'
execute(@SQL)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: @data wont be accessable because dynamic sql has its own scope.

Comment: Good point.
But I don't see the need for the temporary table. Surely a dynamic query selecting directly from 'Comp' is the same in this case ??
declare ATfieldName varchar(100) = 'Name'
declare ATSQL varchar(100) = 'select ' + ATfieldname + ' from Comp where Dept = 25 and Extension=101'
execute(ATSQL);
(sorry for all the 'AT's...it wouldn't let me post with the symbol)

Comment: I don't that either, but your query just wouldn't work that way. Instead it would raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Given your WHERE clause and temp table you might simply select from the table instead, avoiding that temp table.  This example uses a `CASE`, modify/add to it if you need more columns; use other parameters if you need for the Dept and Ext, no tricky code for that needed.

Use `TOP 1` if you only need one if there are multiple matches.

```
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(50)
SET @col = 'Name'
SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN (@col='Name') THEN Comp.Name
   WHEN (@col='Surname') THEN Comp.Surname
 END AS SearchName
FROM Comp 
WHERE Comp.Dept=25 
  AND Comp.Ext=101
```

Note that this does not use dynamic SQL and can be set as a parameterized query making it more secure.

Here is a simple fiddle to test this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78920/2/0